# Bucle FOR anidado java netbeans

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de ingresar en un JTABLE una secuencia de números a traves de un ciclo FOR anidado, pero no me funciona. Como se muestra en la imagen, quiero que la tercera columna de la tabla se llene empezando desde el número 28560 hasta 28580, pero se me llena con un mismo número que es 28579
[image: imagen]

A continuación les muestro el código, espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano gracias 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Gracias por sus respuestas, he intendado de las dos formas que han mencionado pero sigue lo mismo, solo me muestra un mismo numero, no me muestra la secuencia de un numero hasta otro 
es decir si empiezo por 28560, deberia seguir 28561, 28562.... hasta 28580.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablaSe.getModel();
    int limitex = Integer.parseInt(combo_caja.getSelectedItem().toString());
    String dato = txtdato.getText().toString();
    String inicio = txtinicio.getText().toString();
    String fin = txtfinal.getText().toString();

    int n_inicio = Integer.parseInt(inicio);
    int n_fin = Integer.parseInt(fin);

    String valor="";
    for( int i = 0; i < limitex; i++ ){
        for (int j=n_inicio; j< n_fin; j++ ){
            valor = dato + "" + (j+1);
            modelo.setValueAt(valor, i, 2);
        }

    }

    tablaSe.setModel(modelo);
```

NECESITO SU AYUDA PORFA!

Comment: por favor, edita tu pregunta y pone tu código como texto, no como imagen

Answer (score 1):

El error es que la instrucción `modelo.setValueAt(valor,i,2);` debe ir dentro del for j.

```
for(int j = n_inicio; j < n_fin; j++){
        j = j + 1;
        valor = dato + "" + j;
        modelo.setValueAt(valor,i,2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en la linea de código

```
j=j+1;
```

Del `for` interno, si necesita que `j` sea un número mayor entonces elimine la linea que le mencione y cambie la siguiente por:

```
valor = dato + "" + (j+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Según tu consulta no veo por que utilizar un for anidado, en mi opinion con uno solo debería de bastar-

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablaSe.getModel();
    int limitex = Integer.parseInt(combo_caja.getSelectedItem().toString());
    String dato = txtdato.getText().toString();
    String inicio = txtinicio.getText().toString();
    String fin = txtfinal.getText().toString();

    int n_inicio = Integer.parseInt(inicio);
    int n_fin = Integer.parseInt(fin);

    String valor="";
    for( int i = n_inicio ; i < n_fin; i++ ){
            valor = dato + "" + (i+1);
            modelo.setValueAt(valor, i, 2);
         //opcional (no se que función cumple el limitex, tal vez deberías de dar un poco más de información)
         if(i == limitex){
         break;
         }

    }

    tablaSe.setModel(modelo);
```

sin embargo  (no se que función cumple el limitex, no es claro. Tal vez deberías de dar un poco más de información).
Un saludo.